# Log file to confirm SFTP Upload

Tags: linux, sh, sftp, lftp

I am accessing a SFTP via LFTP using the script below.  It runs from cron at 4/11/16/23.  For some unknown reason at unknown intervals I am getting failures.  How can print a log file that will confirm ls -l for the file I am uploading? I am hoping it can be wrapped into the existing script.  Is there a better way to log a confirm than ls -l?

```
# Upload to SFTP via LFTP
#
host="hostname.com"
user="usrname"
pass="passw"
rdir="remote/dir"
file="upload-file.txt"

lftp -u $user,$pass sftp://$host -e "cd $rdir ; put $file ; bye"
#
```

Comment: what does  a negative score mean? can anyone help?

Comment: can anyone help? Google doesnt seem to have an example close enough that I can understand and the man pages are still a little bit beyond my understanding.......

Answer (score 0):

You can enable debug using, well, the "debug" command. With -o FILE option it can save the debug output to the file. Also you can add "ls -l >> file" after put command to append the ls output to the file.

For example:

```
lftp -e "debug -o debug.log; put file; ls file >> remote-ls.log; bye" sftp://user:pass@host.example.com/remote/path
```

Comment: He wants to get the state of the file on the remote system, not the local system. "ls" won't list files on remote systems.

Comment: Inside the quotes after -e option there are lftp commands and an ls there would print the state of the remote file.

Comment: Lav - can you give me an example on how I would go about using the -o option to save ls on the remote to a folder on my local?

Comment: I have added an example to my answer.